# Check if file exists (Overwrite if does) PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to create a simple form that allows users to upload files to the server. However, I am getting an error when a user uploads a file with the same name as one that is already on the server... What I would like for it to do is if the file exists, delete the old one and upload the new one. I have tried:

```
if (file_exists($_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["name"], $temp);
```

but it generates an error  Warning: move_uploaded_file() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in....
I am new at PHP, and have read php.net's description on how to do this, and still confused
Could anyone help get this resolved?
Source code:

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "pdf", "avi", "bmp", "css", "csv", "html", "js", "json","mdb", "exe", "xls", "pptx", "xlsx", "docx", "doc", "ppt", "pub",  "wma", "wmv", "rtf", "txt", "zip" );
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/pdf")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/x-msvideo")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/bmp")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "text/css")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "text/csv")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "text/html")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/javascript")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/json")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/x-msaccess")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/x-msdownload")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.ms-excel")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/x-mspublisher")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/x-ms-wma")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/x-ms-wmv")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/msword")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/rtf")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "text/plain")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/zip"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  } else {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
        if (file_exists($_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["name"], $temp);
    } else {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: ". $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    }
  }
} else {
  echo "Invalid file";
}
?>

<!--<script>
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.href = './.index.php'; // the redirect goes here

    }, 5000); // 5 seconds
</script>-->
```

Comment: It's given you the answer in the warning, `$temp` is an array. You need to pass the file name, not an array of the exploded file name in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use an array for a destination. You need to specify where you want the file to be placed. Try this:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

That will put it in the upload folder.

Comment: Knew it was simple as this. Just not the best at reading error codes. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

you are using here this. `explode` function returns array. this below line causing the problem

```
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

move_uploaded_file() expects a string as second parameter. But your are trying to use an array. 
The second parameter represents the destination of the file you are moving.